# I am creating a heading which changes font every second, but how to do i change the variable to set it to another font? css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a heading which changes font every second, but how to do i change the variable to set it to another font.
https://replit.com/@WHATman69/WoodenOrchidRevisioncontrol#script.js
for code.

i tried watching tutorials but everthing was too confusing

```js
var root = document.querySelector(":root");
var rootstyles = getComputedStyle(root);
var red = rootstyles.getPropertyValue(--red);
console.log("red: ", red);
```

```css
:root {
  --red: "verdana";
}

h1,
p {
  font-family: var(--red);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Fortune cookie!</h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">Check your luck by clicking the cookie!</p>
```

Comment: Please put the code into your question.

Comment: @AHaworth its too long

Comment: Hi, we almost never need absolutely everything, just enough to show the problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you investigated setProperty?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const root = document.querySelector(":root");

const fonts = ['Arial', 'verdana']
let index = 0

setInterval(() => {
  root.style.setProperty('--font', fonts[index % fonts.length])
  index += 1
}, 1000)
```

```css
:root {
  --font: "verdana";
}

h1,
p {
  font-family: var(--font);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Fortune cookie!</h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">Check your luck by clicking the cookie!</p>
```